# Combine Data of Two Tables in single DropDown using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

> **Problem**: I have Two Tables Users and Users Group and in front end on
> request of that particular page need to send all data from both the
> table together, as there is specific drop down to show them both, and after done with the operation of that page data will get back in POST request (current models structures is given below), i am not getting how do i make connection in all these three tables so that it will get managed, Please let me know.

Model: User.py

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="username", unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.DateField(verbose_name="created_by", auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password', 'hardware_id']

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_role_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_role_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    objects = UserManager()
```

Model: UserGroup.py

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Users)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Model: Rules.py

```
class Rules(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    # Here i need to mention the code for field where i can store the combined value of User and UserGroup [selected from the dropdown].

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> **Need Solution:**
>
> 1. How do i code in View to fetch the data of Two tables to send them for DropDown. {GET Request}
> 2. How will i store the values for the same together in Rules Table { As i said DropDown consist both values and can be selected all
>    together. }
> 3. The Structure of the Model {with the required Changes}.

Comment: can you add your data expectation?

Comment: can i add screenshot of design? or diagram

Comment: anything to make it more clear. even an example of with 2 users and rules and groups is enough.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eXOUBS-FMm5IdEYGfn4403A5x7ODoII9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the url you can see the screenshot of the Rule FrontEnd there is a Drop Down where both User and UserGroups are visible and later on at last these data get back as request of POST,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no out of the box solution for that. I can advise to seprate this dropdown into two. First with UserGroup, second with User. You can fill user dropdown based on selected UserGroup with ajax or htmx -> [htmx value-select](https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/)

In your model Rules (should be Rule)
add fields:

```
 user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

if there can be only one rule per Users(this should also be User)/UserGroup add unique_toigether to model Rules:

```
unique_together = ['user', 'group']
```

[django docs unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Comment: okay @Waldemar i am working accordingly let you know if any issue again